# What is the <figure> tag for?

Tags: html, figure

I found several tutorials that recommend to wrap images or logos in `<figure>`.
What I have seen so far is that it adds some kind of margin around the image and changes the display property from inline-block to block (apparently), but in terms of SEO and even HTML architecture, what is the benefit of using `<figure>`?

from W3schools:

```
<figure>
  <img src="img_pulpit.jpg" alt="The Pulpit Rock" width="304" height="228">
</figure>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/Tags/tag_figure.asp

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First off, [avoid using W3Schools](http://w3fools.com) please. Main reason being is that they post a lot of inaccurate information. A better place that's been evolving for web development can be found on the [Mozilla Developer Network (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML).

Specifically on their <[figure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figure)> page.

> A `<figure>` is basically just another HTML5 element that's tailored to be more semantic to the structure of the HTML that's created. It's the same reason why we have `<article>`, `<section>`, `<aside>`, and `<nav>` tags were created, so that the content is better understood by developers and bots alike when reading the source of a page instead of having `<div>` thrown around everywhere to make it all confusing.

Comment: I liked this line `First off, avoid using W3Schools please`. Much correct statement; w3schools still running on old content.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, `<figure>` tag in HTML5 is a combination of HTML `<img>` + `<pre> tag for code snippet`.

Quoted from MDN

> Usually this is an image, an illustration, a diagram, a code snippet,
>   or a schema that is referenced in the main text, but that can be moved
>   to another page or to an appendix without affecting the main flow.